# visual studio 2012 working on two forms side by side

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have two aspx.cs forms that I'm trying to work on.  My goal would be to have two aspx.cs forms open, allowing me to basically copy off one into the other - having both of them open at the same time. Is something like that possible? or do I need to have two screens, even in that case, how would I be able to do that.

I know it's possible for me to take one of the forms and just drag it to the side so it's seperate from all the other forms. I'm workign in TFS (btw)

Comment: open two instance of visual studio and open files aspx.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to Window on the menu and select New Vertical Tab Group. This will open up an additional tab group that you can move tabs in and out of within the same Visual Studio instance.